# How to check if a variable/loop in Python was True?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning Python and had a small issue. I have this loop:

```
found = None 
print ('Before', found)
for value in [ 41, 5, 77, 3, 21, 55, 6]:
    if value == 21:
        found = True
    else: 
        found = False 
    print (found, value)
print ('After', found)
```

The code is well, but the issue is `print ('After', found)` I want it to tell me that there was a `True` value found in the loop. Is there a way to keep the code the way it is and resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to *reset* `found` to `False` once you've set it to `True`. Initialize it to `False`, then only set it to `True` if `value == 21`; don't do anything if `value != 21`.

```
found = False 
print ('Before', found)
for value in [ 41, 5, 77, 3, 21, 55, 6]:
    if value == 21:
        found = True
    print (found, value)
print ('After', found)
```

Ignoring the `print` statement in the loop, you could just use `any`:

```
found = any(value == 21 for value in [ 41, 5, 77, 3, 21, 55, 6])
```

or even

```
found = 21 in [ 41, 5, 77, 3, 21, 55, 6]
```

Comment: I appreciate the response and understand some of the code but the problem is on the terminal. It prints "True 21, 55, 6" but that's incorrect. I want it to be "True" only for the value 21 and back to 'False' for the other values and print 'True' for the code "print ('After', found)". I hope that makes sense!

Comment: @FruitBoy - in that case you can set `found = value == 21` inside your `for` loop. And just below that, `print(found, value)`.